# Submit form without loosing soft keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have been trying to find a similar post to this question within the forum with no success. I have a simple form composed by a textarea and a button to submit on  a app using angularJS. It works fine. However, when I press submit I loose the focus of the textarea so the keyboard disappears, and when I press on the textarea shows off again. I would like to keep it visible even if I press submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try attaching a handler to `focusout` event and focus the `textarea` inside that handler.

If you want to focus back to `textarea` only when the `button` is clicked, you can attach the handler to your `button`'s `click` event instead.

```js
//This will prevent textarea from being focused out
//$("textarea").on("focus", function(e) {
//  $(this).focus();
//});

$("button").on("click", function(e) {
  $("textarea").focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: It works like a charm :D I was wondering if there is any other option that does not require javascript?

Comment: I have just realized now that then I can not hide the keyboard if I press out of the form scope

Comment: You can attach the handler to `textarea`'s `onfocusout` propertydirectly from html `<textarea onfocusout="$(this).focus()"></textarea>`. Though, it is still javascript and I would recommend keeping javascript code in your js files.

Comment: @Tekerson, You can focus back to textarea only when the button is clicked, if you want to focus out when clicking anywhere else. See updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**First option** Just use this, you can use html5 auto focus attribute

For Example:

```
<input type="text" name="name" autofocus="autofocus" id="yourtextboxid" />
```

If this code not will work do this thing.
**Second Option**

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#yourtextboxid').attr("autofocus","autofocus");
     }
```